# Convert an Object of Key-Value into an Array of Key-Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I have this Object:

```
const data = {id: "value", project_id: "value", task_id: "value", hours: "value", started_time: "value", task_id: "value"}
```

I wanted to convert it into an Array that still has that key:value pair like this:

```
[id: "value", 
project_id: "value", 
task_id: "value", 
hours: "value", 
started_time: "value",
ended_time: "value",
notes: "value", 
task_id: "value"]
```

I've tried using

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const arr = [(`${key}:${value}`)]
    console.log(arr)
})
```

but it returned 8 individual arrays and the key-value pair was gone.

```
["id: value"]
["project_id: value"]
["task_id: value"]
["hours: value"]
["started_time: value"]
["ended_time: value"]
["notes: value"]
["task_id: value"]
```

Although I can use `.contact()`, as I have mentioned, the key-value pair was gone.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your expected array is not a valid array.

Comment: You can't have key/value arrays in that sort of way

Comment: it actually "returned" nothing, all you did was console log an array with a single string as an item, you haven't actually done anything - consider using `Object.entries(data).map` and `return \`${key}:${value}\`` - the result will be what you want

Comment: As Jaromanda X1 says, perhaps you want an array of strings like `['id:value', 'project_id: value', ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `.map`

```js
var obj = {
    id: "value", 
    project_id: "value", 
    task_id: "value", 
    hours: "value", 
    started_time: "value",
    ended_time: "value",
    notes: "value"
};
var returnValue = Object.keys(obj).map(key => `${key}: ${obj[key]}`)
console.log(returnValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution.

```js
var object = {
    id: "value", 
    project_id: "value", 
    task_id: "value", 
    hours: "value", 
    started_time: "value",
    ended_time: "value",
    notes: "value", 
    task_id: "value"
};

var array = [];
Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    array.push(key+":"+value);

});
 console.log(array)
```